# DotnetCore - SharpApp - Parcel Template Server Issue

Tags: .net-core, servicestack

I have been working with SharpApp by ServiceStack, I read the documentation to start with parcel-web template.
https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/parcel-webapp

I downloaded the code and using command prompt, go the client folder. I follow the steps:

```
npm install -g parcel-bundler
```

Then I run

```
npm run dev
```

Then I open new command prompt and go to the client folder, then I type

```
npm run server
```

I get following output:

> E:\Trace3\Samples\Trace3TaskPane\client>npm run server
>
> my-app@0.1.0 server E:\Trace3\Samples\Trace3TaskPane\client
>   dotnet build -c Release ../server && node scripts/copy-server.js && web ../app/app.settings
>
> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Core
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Restore completed in 31.12 ms for E:\Trace3\Samples\Trace3TaskPane\server\server.csproj.
>     server -> E:\Trace3\Samples\Trace3TaskPane\server\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\server.dll
>
> Build succeeded.
>       0 Warning(s)
>       0 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.64
>   Using 'E:\Trace3\Samples\Trace3TaskPane\app\app.settings'
>   Attempting to load plugin 'plugins/server.dll', size: 4608 bytes
>   Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

According to the documentation

> Then to start the ServiceStack Server to host your Web App run:
>
> $ npm run server
>
> > Which will host your App at http://localhost:5000 which in debug mode will enable hot reloading which will automatically reload your web page as it detects any file changes made by parcel.

Please suggest how to fix this?

Regards,
Jamil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Server` library project needed to be a `netstandard2.0` project which has been updated in the latest [parcel-webapp](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/parcel-webapp) project template, so if you create a new project, e.g:

```
$ x new parcel-webapp ProjectName
```

You should be able to run the server as expected:

```
$ npm run server
```

Just like any .NET Core App the port and host to listen to can specified with the [ASPNETCORE_URLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#server-urls) Environment variable which you can set on **Windows** before running the npm script, e.g:

```
$ SET ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://localhost:8080
$ npm run server
```

Or if you prefer you can include it in the npm script in `package.json`, e.g:

```
"scripts": {
  "server": "SET ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://localhost:8080 && dotnet build -c Release ../server && node scripts/copy-server.js && x ../app/app.settings",
},
```

> To set an Environment variable in macOS or Linux remove the `SET` prefix.

Comment: how can we change the url port? not to use 5000? Where to configure it?

Comment: @Jamil You can add `port xxx` in your app.settings see [Sharp Apps](https://sharpscript.net/docs/sharp-apps) for some examples. Alternatively just like a normal .NET Core App you can specify it in the [ASPNETCORE_URLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#server-urls) Environment variable to change it.

Comment: following your suggestion, I set the different port and it works fine but to set the custom base URL. e.g: by default, it runs with http://localhost:PORT, I am trying to host with custom URL e.g: http;//mysite.local/ I tried to use ASPNETCORE_URLs, but it does not work. Please suggest what I am making a mistake here. Here are the app settings.

name Parcel Web App
debug true
URLs http://mjnsoft.local

Comment: I tried but it's not working. Here is what I am doing. I updated my package.json file as you suggested. Then on cmd in the client folder, I type "npm run build". It compiles and builds the application. Then on the cmd, I navigate to the "app" folder and I type "x" to run the app. It runs the application but it still shows to use http://localhost:5000

Comment: @Jamil If you're updating your npm scripts than you need to run the script to start your app, ie. `npm run server`, if you're running `x` from the `/app` folder you need to have the environment variable set, either by setting the it first `SET ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://localhost:8080` before running `x` or in the same command with `SET ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://localhost:8080 && x`.